# Conditional sum using proc sql

Tags: sas

I have a table containing a accrual_date, absence_type, employee_id and duration_days.

```
accrual_date        absence_type  duration_days  employee_id
01JAN2001:00:00:00  010           10.20          1
01JAN2001:00:00:00  014           11             1
01JAN2002:00:00:00  015           30             2
01JAN2001:00:00:00  015           20             2
```

I would like to create a query that sum the duration_days per emplid per absence type. So the result should be like:

```
employee_id       duration_days_010   duration_days_014  duration_days_015
1                 10.20               11                 .
2                 .                   .                  50
```

Add a column containing the duration_daysper absence_type per employee_id:

```
proc sql;
create table sort_second as
select 
        case when absence_type='014' then sum(duration_days) else . end as duration_days_014,
        case when absence_type='015' then sum(duration_days) else . end as duration_days_015,
        case when absence_type='010' then sum(duration_days) else . end as duration_days_010,
        employee_id, absence_type
    from sort_first
    group by emplid;

quit;
```

Then remove the duplicate keys:

```
proc sort data=sort_second out=test1 nodupkey;
by emplid;
quit;
```

But what this code does is disregards that it's from 014 or 015 or 010 and add it all for an employee. Like this:

```
employee_id       duration_days_010   duration_days_014  duration_days_015
    1                 21.20               21.20          .
    2                 .                   .                  50
```

Kindly advise what went wrong. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, if you're in SAS I would recommend using SAS tools!

In this case, either a `PROC FREQ` or better `PROC TABULATE` would do this directly, and if you want a dataset you can get that with `ODS OUTPUT`.

```
ods output table=want;
proc tabulate data=have;
where absence_type in (10,14,15);
class absence_type employee_id;
var duration_days;
tables employee_id,absence_type*duration_days*sum;
run;

proc transpose data=want out=final prefix=duration_days_;
by employee_id;
id absence_type;
var duration_days_sum;
run;
```

---

If you want to stick with SQL, what you need to do is change how the case statements work.

```
case when absence_type='014' then sum(duration_days) else . end as duration_days_014,
```

should be

```
sum(case when absence_type='014' then duration_days else . end) as duration_days_014,
```

IE, you want to sum an imaginary column that just has the 014 duration days in it.  What you're doing in your example is inserting the sum of all duration_days in any column that the employee has any duration_days in.   You also should be able to skip most of the steps above - you can do this from the initial dataset.

```
proc sql;
create table final as
select 
        sum (case when absence_type=014 then duration_days else . end) as duration_days_014,
        sum (case when absence_type=015 then duration_days else . end) as duration_days_015,
        sum (case when absence_type=010 then duration_days else . end) as duration_days_010,
        employee_id
    from have
    group by employee_id;

quit;
```

Comment: In PROC SQL you can also use a boolean (1 or 0) to conditionally sum, like `sum(duration_days *(absence_type=14)) as duration_14`.  The 'absence_type = 14' bit will resolve to 1 when true and 0 when false.  About the same, I just find it more readable than SQLs awful 'CASE'.

Comment: That certainly does work; I tend to prefer case, despite its awfulness, because it's more clear to other readers of the code exactly what it's doing.  Equal signs can be easily missed, unfortunately.